# Jenkins trigger build job on PR & deploy on merge

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, pull-request

I have two Jenkins job `Build` & `Deploy`. Build job builds the artifact and creates a version number `X.X.X`

On successful build, it triggers the `Deploy` job with builded version `X.X.X`

Right now when a PR is merged I trigger `Build` job which also deploys.

But I want to trigger `Build` job when a PR is raised & `Deploy` it on successful merge. I can achieve this in following ways:

- Instead of two jobs, now I create 3 jobs: `PRBuild`, `Build` & `Deploy`. `PRBuild` is the new job which will be duplicate of `Build` but it will not trigger `Deploy`. But this will cost extra management.
- Another solution, I only have 2 jobs `Build` & `Deploy`. `Build` will be triggered on PR raise & `Deploy` on merge. But in this, somehow I have to pass the version to `Deploy` job which I don't know how to do it.

What is the best way to achieve this, is there any Jenkins plugin available? Should I change my strategy?